# Why Server Responds manifest.json Request With index.html?

Tags: .htaccess, manifest.json

.htaccess

```
# force traffic to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# serve index.html for any unknown paths
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

because the request returned is `index.html` browser throws error like this `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.`

All Requests For Script Or Css Work Except This One.

Comment: How are you requesting this file? What request is the browser making (to what URL is it making the request)? Where are you expecting this file to be served from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you are using a relative URL-path in your client-side JavaScript to this `manifest.json` file so the browser resolves this incorrectly (relative to the URL in the address bar, not the file-path on the server as you are perhaps expecting), resulting in a 404 (which routes the request to `index.html`).

You need to use a root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute (scheme + hostname) URLs when referencing any assets from client-side code when you are rewriting the URL from different URL-path depths.